# Publish two webcam simultaneously one NetStream

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, webcam, flash-media-server

Who to publish two webcam simultaneously one NetStream?
I like to show one webcam in 78*78 size top corner of the main webcam (main webcam is full screen). Both videos is live.

Please advise me.
Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Just create two NetStreams